# badarg to '++'operator - How to come around?

Tags: list, erlang, arguments, operators

> ```
> ** Reason for termination =
> ** {badarg,[{erlang,'++',[<<>>,"</after></set></query></iq>"]},
>             {geoloc,get_nearby,1},
> ```

And the method was:

```
get_nearby({_Pid, DynVars})->
        %Last = ts_dynvars:lookup(last, DynVars),
        Last = lists:keysearch(last,1,DynVars),
        {ok, Rad} = ts_dynvars:lookup(rad,DynVars),
        {ok, Lat} = ts_dynvars:lookup(lat,DynVars),
        {ok, Lon} = ts_dynvars:lookup(lon,DynVars),
        if is_tuple(Last) ->
                {value,{Key,After}} = Last,
                if length(After) == 0 ->
                        After2 = "0";
                true ->
                        After2 = After
                end,
                "<iq id=\"" ++ common:get_random_string(5,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-+=") ++ "\" xmlns=\"http://xmpp.xgate.com.hk/plugins\" to=\"xmpp.xgate.hk.com\" type=\"get\"><query xmlns=\"jabber:iq:geoloc\"><geoloc><lat>" ++ Lat ++ "</lat><lon>" ++ Lon ++ "</lon><radius>" ++ Rad ++ "</radius></geoloc><set xmlns=\"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm\"><max>" ++ integer_to_list(ran_max()) ++ "</max><after>" ++ After2 ++ "</after></set></query></iq>";
        true ->         % Last is boolean, namely the 'false' atom
                ts_dynvars:set([rad, lat, lon], [Rad, Lat, Lon], DynVars),
                "<iq id=\"" ++ common:get_random_string(5,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-+=") ++ "\" xmlns=\"http://xmpp.xgate.com.hk/plugins\" to=\"xmpp.xgate.hk.com\" type=\"get\"><query xmlns=\"jabber:iq:geoloc\"><geoloc><lat>" ++ Lat ++ "</lat><lon>" ++ Lon ++ "</lon><radius>" ++ Rad ++ "</radius></geoloc><set xmlns=\"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm\"><max>" ++ integer_to_list(ran_max()) ++ "</max></set></query></iq>"
        end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a binary (`<<>>`) and a string, but `++` can only concatenate two strings (or lists - Erlang strings are actually lists).

That means that `After2` is a binary, and consequently it received this value in the second clause of the `if` expression.  Normally calling `length(After)` when `After` is not a list would cause a `badarg` exception, but as it appears in an `if` test it is treated as a guard test and exceptions are ignored, and therefore `length(After) == 0` is treated as false.  So the corresponding value was a binary already when you got it in `DynVars`.

A few suggestions:

- To check whether a list is empty, it is somewhat wasteful to call `length` on it, as `length` needs to go through the entire list.  Instead, write something like:

  ```
  case After of
      "" ->
          After2 = "0";
      [_|_] ->
          After2 = After
  end
  ```

  `[_|_]` is a pattern that matches non-empty lists.  In your case, the value of `After` would not match any of the clauses, and you'd have a `case_clause` error that tells you what value you actually got.

  Of course, if you actually expect a binary here, check for `<<>>` and `<<_/binary>>` instead.
- You're doing quite a few concatenations (`++`) there.  In the expression `A ++ B`, the `++` operator needs to walk along the entire list in `A`, and thus the run time is proportional to the length of `A`.

  There are two common alternatives to concatenation.  First, often the function that will consume the result doesn't actually need a flat list, but would be equally happy with a "deep list" or "iolist" - instead of `"foo" ++ "bar"`, write `["foo", "bar"]`.  Notably, if you're going to write the result to a file or send it to a socket, both `file:write` and `gen_tcp:send` accept both variants.

  Second, you could use binaries instead of strings.  Binaries are different from strings in many interesting ways (not the least how they behave with respect to garbage collection), but they do have the nice property that they can be concatenated efficiently.  If `A` and `B` are binaries, and you write `C = <<A/binary, B/binary>>`, and the compiler can see that you only use `C` but not `A` after that, `B` will simply be concatenated to the memory area that held `A`.  See [the chapter on binary handling in the Efficiency Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html) for more details.
- The two lines starting with `"<iq id=\""` are nearly identical, except that the first one inserts `"<after>" ++ After2 ++ "</after>"` in the middle.  You could have the first case clause set `MaybeAfter = "<after>" ++ After2 ++ "</after>"` and the second case clause set `MaybeAfter = ""`, and then have one single line that inserts the value of `MaybeAfter` in the right place.  That would help making the code more readable.